# Is UserExtendedProperties ANID2 consistent across devices?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, identity

I'm in a situation where I need to find out if an application is used by the same user but on different windows phone device. In other words I need some kind of user ID that is consistent for application on all WP8 devices.

Is ANID2 property of `UserExtendedProperties` suitable for this purpose? If not, what options do I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes ANID2 is the essentially the Windows Live Account Id, this will satisfy your requirements.  This will not differ form device to device, note that ANID2 is only available on WP8 and from WP8 applications.

Answer (score 4):

**ANID2 is bounded to** the the **Windows Live Account Id**, and the **Publisher GUID**. So, applications from **different publisher will get different values of ANID2**.

This link dives into a bit more details-   [ANID2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-us/7e265aed-1719-4158-bc98-5d985e694c4c/userextendedproperties-anid-anid2-changes-in-wp8?forum=wpdevelop)

extract :

**The following holds true for Windows Phone 8 too.**

The format in WP7 was like (I x-ed out a few chars): **`A=E32ACBXXXXXXXXX3B337B68CFFFFFFFF&E=d59&W=1`**

In WP7 it was necessary to parse the value after A= up to &E= as the other values could change over time.